# What does hog the mirror mean?

Tags: meaning

what does the phrase "hog the mirror" mean? I think I am just not sure what "hog" means. I heard it in a talk show.

Comment: The definition of HOG is "Harley Owner Group"

Comment: [Hog](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hog#hog__13). Please check a dictionary before asking here.

Comment: That use of *hog* is informal, and may not be widely known. Are you a non-native speaker of English? Please also visit our sister site for Learners at ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hog something is to not let someone else use it

> verb, informal
>
> keep or use all of (something) for oneself in an unfair or selfish way.
>
> synonyms:  monopolize, dominate, take over, corner, control

So in a house with one mirror, you can have two people needing to use it, if one of them keeps standing in front of it, he/she is hogging the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

People don't only 'hog the mirror', they 'hog' much else besides. They 'hog' the phone (not so common since mobiles arrived), the bathroom, the cooker, the breakfast cereal etc. The point is a 'hog' is a pig. And the reference is to someone behaving, perhaps figuratively, as a pig would behave, and grasping everything to him or herself.

Comment: @J.R. Your edit J.R. was smart but not smart enough. You have missed the much larger grammatical error in my comment. You have strained at a gnat and swallowed a camel! Spot the now 'deliberate mistake'!

Comment: Sorry, it's not my job to proofread your work. Something jumped out at me, so I fixed it. This is not a challenge, a competition etc.

Comment: @J.R. Well I'll tell you then. It should be 'grasping everything to HIM or herself', not 'his'. It is the residue of dialect speech with which I grew up. In Norfolk they say 'He should be ashamed of HIS-self'.

Comment: Well, what are you telling me for? Click the edit button and fix it.

Comment: If it's the "residue of dialect speech," then is it really a "grammatical error"? Or is it merely a dialectal difference? Who are we to tell those from Norfolk that they habitually use the "wrong" pronoun? Besides, we're only talking about a pig – or are we? (Or did you not notice that ambiguity?) Had I been your editor, I would have suggested more changes than the one you made. Thankfully, though, I'm not your editor, and besides, your point was made just fine. My original intent was merely to clean up a stray terminator..

Comment: @J.R. It was that I used 'his' instead of 'him', as in 'his-self'. But I am troubled by the idea that we should go back to incorporating 'dialect' words and speech into standard English. 'Let children spell as they speak' was a daft idea of the 1970s, and it had its casualties. The Victorians went to great lengths to create a standard English on both sides of the Atlantic in the 19th century. Are you suggesting we turn the clock back to where you have Senators and journalists in Washington speaking and writing like characters out of Mark Twain? I realise there may be a couple who already do!

Comment: @J.R. What was the point about the 'pig'?